# IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 8001010a

Tags: asp.net, com-interop, word-automation

This is working fine with Visual Studio's server but when the server is changed to IIS, it throws:

> Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {00020906-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 8001010a.

```
        object initial_limits = 0;
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object Visible = true;
        object openfilename = @"C:\letters\Templates\" + template_src_dropdown.SelectedValue + ".doc";
        current_date = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

        object savefilename = @"C:\letters\Letters\" + reference_id + ".doc";


        ApplicationClass WordApp = new ApplicationClass();
        Document WordDoc = new Document();
        Document docActive = null;
        WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);


        //Document 



        //WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(ref openfilename, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);          

        /*
        if (new_file_chkbox.Checked == true)
        {

            WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        }
        else
        {
            WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(ref openfilename, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        }
        */


        try
        {


            docActive = WordApp.ActiveDocument;
            Bookmark bookmark1;
            bookmark1 = docActive.Bookmarks.Add("word_content", ref missing);
            Range rng_bookmark1 = bookmark1.Range;

            rng_bookmark1.Text = reference_id + "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t" + current_date;
            rng_bookmark1.Text += employee_list_word + vendor_list_word;
            rng_bookmark1.Text += "\n" + subject_txtbox.Text + "\n\n";
            rng_bookmark1.Text += "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t" + designation_dropdown.SelectedValue + "\n";
            rng_bookmark1.Text += "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t" + department_dropdown.SelectedValue + "\n";
            rng_bookmark1.Text += cc_employee_list_word + cc_vendor_list_word;



            try
            {
                WordDoc.SaveAs(ref savefilename, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                WordApp.Visible = true;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label1.Text = ex.Message;
                //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            finally 
            {
                WordApp.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
             }
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Answer (score 1):

VS server is development server and IIS is deployment server.
This is simple to understand that in web application you cant get the features of desktop application because if that happens then no one gonna get a licenced version of MS Word.
It ll becum multicuser then...
Better USE OpenXml ...
Good examples of openXml are provided in Code project.com